# What files should I cache in service-worker install event?

Tags: service-worker, offline-caching, progressive-web-apps

I followed instructions from the [Google PWA tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/) here to make my own app with offline functionality. When I ran Lighthouse check on my `localhost:3000`, I got a report that said everything is setup fine.

[image]

Note that I had only cached my index file and svg image assets only.

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open('word-cloud-v1')
      .then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll([
          '/',
          '/index.html',
          './images/paper-plane.svg',
          './images/idea.svg',
          './images/desk-lamp.svg',
          './images/stopwatch.svg',
          './images/pie-chart.svg',
        ])
      })
  )
})
```

But when I go offline and try to run my app, I get errors that some files have not loaded.

[image]

So I go back and add some more files to cache. Note that this file is not created by me.

```
.then(cache => {
  return cache.addAll([
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    './static/js/bundle.js',
    './images/paper-plane.svg',
    './images/idea.svg',
    './images/desk-lamp.svg',
    './images/stopwatch.svg',
    './images/pie-chart.svg',
  ])
})
```

Although the offline feature works fine now, I'm also seeing a bunch of other randomly generated files that are created in the build folder that I have not explicitly cached yet. So what are the files I should cache inside a service worker so they show up in offline mode?

**TLDR; what files should we cache apart from `/`, `/index.html` and images so we can have offline functionality?**

Answer (score 1):

You can cache anything that you would like to cache. Cache data can be of two types.

**1) Static data** - You can cache all your html/css/js/images which are not dynamic. When you plan to cache static data, it would be easy to wild card the files like below instead of choosing individual files. Below block (angular ng service worker. Your helper class might look different)  will cache everything inside "assets" folder.

```
{
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }
```

**2) Dynamic data** - You can cache dynamic data like API JSON response in IndexDB.